# Django get foreign key model type for OneToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

So in Django 1.10 I am trying to extract the model for a specific attribute that is a foreign key in a one-to-many relationship with the parent class. For example:

```
class some_class(models.Model):
    some_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class another_class(models.Model):
    a_field = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    many    = models.ForeignKey(some_class, models.SET_NULL, db_column='some_class_id', related_name='another_class_things', blank=True, null=True)
```

If I was to do:

```
the_class = some_class._meta.get_field('another_class_things').rel.to
```

I get the error:

```
'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'rel'
```

This works alright when there is a one-to-one relationship, however it doesn't work for one-to-many relationships. What is an alternative to get the model of the attribute? (ie: return 'another_class' in the above situation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the model to which the relation points with:

```
# for a one-to-many relation
the_class = some_class._meta.get_field('another_class_things').field.model
```

We here thus obtain with `field` the `ForeignKey` that is used to define the `ManyToOneRel` in reverse, and we then obtain the model where that `ForeignKey` is defined.

Comment: In the case you don't specify a related_name='something', it doesn't work with 'classname_set'. Is there a way to get it to work in this situation? (I believe this is the case because anything '_set' it is a hidden field?)